# R sort list of objects

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have a list of objects {key, value} pairs. For example:

> list.predict

[[1]]

[1] 1.0000000 0.8564264

[[2]]

[1] 2.0000000 0.1980792

I want to sort this list in descending order by the second component of each element (meaning sorting on the sequence of 0.8564264 and 0.1980792).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.predict[ order( sapply(list.predict, "[", 2) ) ]
```

Comment: thanks. WHat if want to order in a descending order ?

Comment: @user3628777  add the `rev` function.